# прокрутка листов в ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

подскажите, как можно увеличить проводимую линию пальцем при быстром нажатии для перелистывания страницы в ViewPager

Comment: есть подозрение, что вы хотите решить задачу, нетривиальным путем. Поэтому лучше опишите проблему целиком. Для вашего решения надо создать свой ViewPager и переопределить onTouchEvent, но лучше не делать этого.

Comment: есть набор кнопок, которые находятся в одном макете xml, есть набор кнопок в другом макете xml, вставляю их на разные листы viewPager'а, есть вероятность того что при быстром нажатии, можно случайно перелистнуть страницу. это нежелательно.